# media responsible navbar no bootstrap

Tags: html, css

im a newbie in web, so i need your help.
problem: i need to create a responsible navbar, but some piece of code didn't work at all

here it is:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 850px) {
    .menu {
        width: 100%;
        max-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    #toggler:checked ~ .menu {
        max-height: 100%;
    }
```

my html:

```
            <section class="menu">
                <ul class="list_navbar">
                    <li><a id="account" href="#">личный кабинет</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">о нас</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">программы</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">контакты</a></li>
                </ul>
            </section>
            <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="images/icon.svg" alt="icon_logo"></a>
            <input type="checkbox" id="toggler">
            <label for="toggler"><svg></svg></label>
```

a devtools didn't help me, bc it didn't show me that @media even affect on #toggler.
what am I doing wrong?

i tried `overflow: visible` for `#toggler:checked ~ .menu`, but nothing happened.

Comment: In what way does it not work? What happens with your current code and what is the expected behavior?